# Flutter Http get coming Null

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

I started to learn work with APIs. I tried an api without authentication reqres.in and it worked for me . But now im trying to get datas from a api which is work with key, and this datas coming null. When i used my key like this on web browsers https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=MY_API_KEY&page=1 its working ( i can see JSON data). But when i use this api key for my working code datas coming null and i couldn't understand why.

Here is my code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Future<Welcome> apiCall() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=84e37baf...(mykey)&page=1'));

    return Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<Welcome>(
          future: apiCall(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var growableList = [];
            List<Result> data = snapshot.data!.results;
            growableList.add(data[0].name);
            return Text('${growableList}');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you debugging what response and response.body at sending?

Comment: I couldn't debug but i checked with postman and response body like what i want

Comment: Also my status code is 200

Comment: just print the result of response.body or the errors of it

Comment: Response body coming json data truely like {"count":147,"next":"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2019-09-01%2C2019-09-30&key=5ac29048d12d45d0949c77038115cb56&page=2&platforms=18%2C1%2C7","previous":null,"results":[{"slug":"borderlands-3","name":"Borderlands 3","playtime":10,"platforms":[{"platform":{"id":4,"name":"PC","slug":"pc"}},{"platform":{"id":187,"name":"PlayStation 5","slug":"playstation5"}},{"platform":{"id":1,"name":"Xbox One","slug":"xbox-one"}},{"platform":{"id":18, ... etc

Comment: after im parsing it like this Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

Comment: I guess problem is in here " return Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));" but still don't know why

Comment: Can i use streambuilder instead of future builder ?

Comment: Could you post your `Welcome.fromJson` method? I agree that the problem is probably there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FutureBuilder`s work by calling the async function and then immediately calling build. This is why you're seeing null. They will rebuild again once the future returns.

Even though you've marked `apiCall` as async the builder will not wait for it to finish. What you need to do is check `snapshot.hasData` which will only be true once the future has completed. When `snapshot.hasData` is false, you need to return a different widget.

It might also be worth using `snapshot.hasError` which is a bool representing if an error occurred while completing the async function.

Try this code out

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Future<Welcome> apiCall() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=84e37baf...(mykey)&page=1'));

    return Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<Welcome>(
          future: apiCall(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              print(snapshot.error);
            }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              var growableList = [];
              List<Result> data = snapshot.data!.results;
              growableList.add(data[0].name);
              return Text('${growableList}');
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but only circularprogressindicator(); working. I waited like 5 mins but there is no data coming.

Comment: Did you try checking the `snapshot.hasError` flag? If I remember correctly `snapshot.hasData` will be false if theres an error. If an error occurs in the async function it isnt printed or caught anywhere that I can tell. I added an if statement for that in the example.

Comment: I tried. Still couldn't fix.

Comment: When i use snapshot.hasError in Future builder im gettin widget error for future builder.

Comment: I accidentally capitalized the `snapshot.Error`. Is that the error youre talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Problem was in dataclass, there  was some classes which has same names and variable problems like int or double, For exmaple When i tried to generate my code with looking example response i used int except double. But response in real getting double variables. Mistakes like this doesn't let me print it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! That makes sense why it wasnt coming through